# jquery which tell to users to wait

Tags: php, jquery

On my php webapp i have to generate some pdf files(between 5 and 20). A this moment I generate the files just before the pages loads, which is not a smart decision at all.

I wish to display the links to the pdf files, and a gif animation for each pdf link, which 'tells' to the user to wait, because that specific file is not available yet. I need to animaion to stop when the file is done.

Do you have any idea about how to implement this?

Comment: First [get an animated gif](http://ajaxload.info/), then [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as following.

- Generate your loading [image](http://ajaxload.info/)
- Download your image
- Add following code anywhere you want to show it

---

```
<img id="loader" src="image-loader.gif" style="display:hidden" />
```

---

- Add following code before sending ajax request/doing another time-taking operation

---

```
<script>
$("#loader").show();
// do ajax
$("#loader").hide();
</script>
```

you're done

Comment: Except you have to add the `$.hide()` to the callback of the Ajax operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [blockui](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) plugin.